Constructing random graphs with given eigenvalues and eigenvectors
In Linial's presentation on SOME PROBLEMS AND RESULTS IN THE
GEOMETRY OF GRAPHS, on slide 7, some relations of properties of graphs to the eigenvalues of their adjacency matrix are listed, e.g.

if $G$ is $d$-regular, then $\lambda_1=d$ and the eigenvector $v_1=1/\sqrt{n}$
$G$ is connected iff $\lambda_1\gt\lambda_2$
$G$ is bipartite iff $\lambda_1=-\lambda_n$
$\chi(G)\ge-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_n}+1$

That leads to the idea of generating random graphs with certain properties by incorporating constraints on eigenvalues and eigenvectors into their generation rather than gambling with probabilistic guarantees.
Question:

what is known about the problem of generating random graphs with a given number of vertices, whose (binary) adjacency matrix has a set of given eigenvalues and possibly also corresponding eigenvectors when the graphs are symmetric and have no parallel edges or self loops?

